# HTMLの値を隠す方法

Tags: html5

以下のようにしてブラウザ画面上で「aaa」の文字が隠れていることは確認できました。
F12などでブラウザツールを出してみると、実際はタグの値が見えてしまいます。
タグ内の値を見ないようにする方法などありませんでしょうか？

```
<input type="hidden"  th:name="test" th:value="aaa" ></input>
```

Comment: ソースやDOMレベルで（存在するが）見えないようにすることは不可能だと思います。

Comment: `aaa`という値は残したまま、ということですよね

Comment: 難読化や暗号化を期待されているのでしょうか？　完全に誰にも見えないならブラウザにも認識されず、元から存在しないのと大差ありません。なにか他に「やりたいこと」があってこの質問がある気がするのですが、そういうことはありませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。セッションにデータを持たせようとしてたのですが、セッションが異なるアプリに対して値を渡すことになり、悩んでいます。どのような方法が一般的なのでしょうか？

Comment: 現在の質問では「それはできません」という答えになってしまうので、アプリ間でのデータの受け渡しが本命なのであればその旨を質問文やタイトルに反映していただくか、別途質問していただけませんか？またその際、どういう場面でどんなアプリに何を伝えたいとか、そのデータはどれぐらい秘密にしないといけないのかといった情報もあると、よりピンポイントなアドバイスができるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

隠すのは不可能です。
値はWebサーバー内だけで保持しておき、ブラウザーに対して値を渡さなければいいのではないでしょうか？ （代わりにセッションIDなどを渡す。）